# Why does $(document).width(); give me two different values on chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, width

Why does `$(document).width();` give me two different values when I refresh the page? When I click on the webpage and inspect element to get my body width and it is 1663(the figure I need) and when I use `$(document).width();` 1663 is what I get the first time the page runs, but when I refresh the page I get 1680, which is presumably the body width plus scrollbar! Anyone any ideas around this bug? This is on chrome only, by the way. It is not doing this in firefox or ie.

Comment: Have you tried getting the width of the body tag instead? or try it with `$('body').css('width')` If you just get width on the doc or the window, the values will be different from what you get in the css due to the scrollbar. You need to sync them by using something in the css (media query) and checking it with js to sync the width in css and js

Comment: Is something getting cached so that maybe an element would load faster the second time around, thus creating different widths?

Comment: Since it is only on chrome, it's probably just something that hasn't loaded when you checked the width. Have you tried checking the width on window load?

Comment: $('body').css('width'); is doing the same thing. One minute it is 1680 the next 1663! Even when I wait until document is ready it gives me both values, it seems to be alternating them!

Comment: If I wait until window.load() it gives me the full width of the window before scrollbar and all elements are loaded so that is not what I need.

Comment: If you're seeking debugging help, we can't do anything but speculate without the relevant code.

Comment: var resize = function() {
    var mainSliderHeight;/*$( window).height(); only gets screen size inc scroll etc*/
    var mainSliderWidth = $(window).width();
    /* container is 90% so need to * by .9 */
    mainSliderWidth = mainSliderWidth * .9;
    /* slider div works on ratio of 2:159  */
    mainSliderHeight = mainSliderWidth/2.159;
    $( "#topSlider" ).css("height",mainSliderHeight);
    $( "#sliderVideo" ).css("height",mainSliderHeight);
      }; 
$(document).ready(resize);
$(window).bind('resize',resize);

Comment: I've used `$(window).width();` `$(document).width();` and `$('body').css('width')`each giving the same 2 versions of the width, one with the scrollbar included and one without, depending on whether I refresh the page or click the link to get to the page!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery width() function on chrome gives me different values on loading and reload(F5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784047/jquery-width-function-on-chrome-gives-me-different-values-on-loading-and-reloa)

Comment: No it doesn't answer it as it tells me to use `window.load()` which is too late when everything is loaded, I need the size before it is loaded. Why the downvotes? Surely this is a valid question?