# Element measured width is different when reloading with CTRL+SHIFT+R vs F5

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that inserts an element and measures it's width. When refreshing with F5 (using cache), the width is 440px. When using CTRL+SHIFT+R (re-download cached files) the width is 290px. Similar questions have suggested using `$(window).load`. But I have tried that and there is no change in behaviour. Running the code inside a 10 second time-out also produces different results.

It would seem like the problem is running the measurement before the css has been applied. But using the load event and/or a 10 second time-out should solve that. It doesn't.

This is Firefox 30. All other scripts are disabled on the page. The JS files are loaded in the footer, the css is loaded in `<head>`.

Sample:

```
var $el = $(...);
$el.css('position','absolute').css('left','-9999999px');
$parent.append($el);
var Width = parseInt($el.outerWidth(), 10);
console.log('Width: '+Width); //290 OR 440
```

Similar questions that do not solve the problem:

[Jquery width() function on chrome gives me different values on loading and reload(F5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784047/jquery-width-function-on-chrome-gives-me-different-values-on-loading-and-reloa)

[jQuery behaving strange after page refresh (F5) in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504982/jquery-behaving-strange-after-page-refresh-f5-in-chrome)

Comment: can you provide any fiddle, where I can check demo ?

Comment: try using `el.offsetWidth` instead of `$el.outerWidth()`

Answer (score 1):

Embed your script using *defer*, like so:

```
<script defer src="yourscript.js"></script>
```

Loading a script with *defer* ensures that it is executed after the document has been parsed (but before firing DOMContentLoaded).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using defer on script tag and put it at the bottom of body tag