# While Loop doesn't work properly - it's skipping sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop

Simple while loop is not working properly. 
I write a script for limiting the text to 3 lines. It's very simple. I check if the height of the element (div) is higher than 3 lines (hardcoded font-size and line-height) and if so, I remove the last word and add ellipses. And I am doing it while string is shortly enough to fit on 3 lines.

It is working randomly, sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. If not working I have only 1 word on the 4th line. So it skips only the final iteration and not every time.

```
$('div.prod-description').each(function(){
    var obj = $(this);

    if(obj.height() > 60) { // line-height: 18px;
        var ellipses = '...';
        var new_text = null;
        while(obj.height() > 60) {
            new_text = obj.text().slice(0, obj.text().lastIndexOf(' '));
            obj.text(new_text+ellipses);
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to remove the `if statement`, I tried with `do while statement` but it's the same.

EDIT: I found the problem! But don't know how to fix it. If I hit enter on the browser's address bar or I come to page from the menu it's working properly. If I refresh with `F5` it's skipping the last iteration. Any ideas?

Comment: You know you can do this with just css. `div { overflow: hidden; height: 60px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: It does work as expected (at least the while part), I see your problem is with having it with 3 lines and the result having four sometimes, that's odd.

Comment: How can I use `text-overflow: ellipsis` on multiline text? It should be cross-browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I was lucky to find that the script doesn't work properly only on refreshing the page with F5 I found the solution. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8310308/1333512

To correct this problem use:

```
$(window).load(function() {});
```

Out instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```