# How to run a Javascript function everytime f5 is used to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, onload-event

The following code works for the first time that the page is loaded but when the page is refreshed using <kbd>F5</kbd>, it does not work on Firefox. In Chrome it works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("iframe").each(function() {
        // Using closures to capture each one
        var iframe = $(this);
        iframe.on("load", function() { // Make sure it is fully loaded
            iframe.contents().click(function(event) {
                iframe.trigger("click");
            });
        });

        iframe.click(function() {
            alert("Clicked...");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: is it the same when you try "ctrl + f5"

Comment: what browser? What errors are thrown?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504982/jquery-behaving-strange-after-page-refresh-f5-in-chrome

Comment: Use `.on()` to attach event handler, like `iframe.on( "click", "a.offsite", function() {
  alert( "Clicked..." );  
});` See the reference: http://api.jquery.com/live/#event-delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('main_iframe').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
    $('iframe').load(function () {
        $(this).contents().find("body").on('click', function (event) {
            alert("clicked....")
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

put all your code in `jQuery(function(){
//here
})` and all will be ok. That runs whens the page loads, each f5 action, remove the other code for testing reload.