# Strange Cache issue Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, caching

I have css applied to few divs through JQuery and I do some animations and modifications to the div width. Everything works fine if I load the page for first time or refresh it using **Shift+F5** but if I enter the url or reload it using just **F5**, the width of the divs look wierd.

**THE EXPECTED OUTPUT (I GET THIS IF I PRESS SHIFT+F5)**

[image: The expected output]

**THE OUTPUT I GET**

[image: Output I receive]

The width of the divs get stretched to the width of browser window.
I dont want to clear cache with javascript cause I want the scripts to be faster.

I use 2 functions for storing css and restoring css of elements

```
function store_elemprop(selector)
{
var elemwidth;
selector.each(function() {
    elemwidth=$(this).width()+20;
    console.log("STORED WIDTH:"+elemwidth);
    $(this).attr("data-elemwidth",elemwidth);
    $(this).css("width",elemwidth)
});     
}



function restore_elemprop(selector) 
{
var ewidth;
  selector.each(function() {
    ewidth=$(this).attr("data-elemwidth");
    console.log("RESTORED WIDTH:"+ewidth);
    $(this).animate({width: ewidth}, 500);  
  });
}
```

**EDITS:**

Now I am getting crazy cause If i open a new tab and put the url, it works fine but if i reload using **F5** in the same tab, it shows the unexpected output.

**I TRIED USING MY PAGE IN INTERNET EXPLORER AND THERE WAS NO PROBLEM BUT THAT WAS NOT THE CASE WITH GOOGLE CHROME**

Comment: Were are you calling those functions?

Comment: I call them when document is ready like store_elemprop($(".galbox_viewpic_cont"));

Comment: Which browser you are using ?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: If I have to make things more elaborate, I am also using bootstrap in my project. The grids are styled like this: 
    
<div class="galbox_viewpic_cont col-sm-3" data-elemwidth="1348" style="width: 1348px;">
<!--The grid contents-->
</div>

Where 1348 is not the expected width. 114 is the expected width

Comment: I can't see the problem from the infromation you have provided so far. Have you tried to run your code in a diffrent browser to check if it is a browser related issue?

Comment: It works well in IE. No issues with IE. Looks like a browser related issue. Any way to overcome it?

Comment: Using $(window).load(function() {}); solved my problem. Thanks for the person who linked it. whoever it may be..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504982/jquery-behaving-strange-after-page-refresh-f5-in-chrome